# Ventanas modales con AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax, bootstrap

Tengo un formulario **ordenes** dentro de una ventana modal, este formulario tiene un `select` y un botón **crear nuevo cliente**. El `select` permite buscar un cliente, por lo tanto, si el cliente no se encuentra registrado, deseo poder agregar un nuevo cliente abriendo otra ventana modal con el formulario **clientes**.

Adjunto una imagen de mi formulario.

[image: Formulario]

Script:

Mi `script` básicamente lo que hace es, mediante el botón con id `btn-btn-create` a través de un evento `on.click`, puedo mostrar la modal con el formulario **crear clientes**, a su vez se oculta la modal con el formulario **crear ordenes**. Al momento de querer registrar y guardar un nuevo cliente, toma las validaciones en ambos formularios. *Aclaro, cada formulario tiene los mismos nombres de `inputs`*

Lo que me gustaría saber es **¿cómo hacer que solo muestre los errores del formulario crear clientes?**

```
$('body').on('click', '.modal-show', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var me = $(this),
        url = me.attr('href'),
        title = me.attr('title');

      $('#modal-title').text(title);
      $('#modal-btn-save').removeClass('hide')
        .text(me.hasClass('edit') ? 'Actualizar' : 'Crear');

      $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response) {
                $('#modal-body').html(response);

                $('#btn-btn-client').click(function(event) {
                  event.preventDefault();


                  $('#modal').modal('hide');
                  $('#modal1').modal('show');

                  $.ajax({
                    url: '/admin/customers/create',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(response) {
                      $('#modal-body1').html(response);
                    }
                  });
                });


                $('#modal-btn-save1').click(function(event) {
                  event.preventDefault();

                  var form = $('#modal-body1 form'),
                    url = form.attr('action'),
                    method = $('input[name=_method]').val() == undefined ? 'POST' : 'PUT';

                  form.find('.help-block').remove();
                  form.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

                  $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: method,
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function(response) {
                      form.trigger('reset');
                      $('#modal1').modal('hide');
                      $('#datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();

                      swal({
                        type: 'success',
                        title: '¡Éxito!',
                        text: '¡Se han guardado los datos!'
                      });
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                      var res = xhr.responseJSON;
                      if ($.isEmptyObject(res) == false) {
                        $.each(res.errors, function(key, value) {
                          $('#' + key)
                            .closest('.form-group')
                            .addClass('has-error')
                            .append('<span class="help-block"><strong>' + value + '</strong></span>');
                        });
                      }
                    }
                  })
                });
```

Acá existen 2 modales, la primera es para el formulario **ordenes** y la segunda es para mostrar el formulario **crear clientes**:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" id="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Form Input</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-btn-save">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" id="modal-header1">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title1" id="modal-title">Form Input</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body1">

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer" id="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-btn-save1">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Este es mi formulario **crear órdenes**:

```
<div class="row">
  {!! Form::model($order, [ 'route' => $order->exists ? ['admin.orders.update', $order->id] : 'admin.orders.store', 'method' => $order->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST' ]) !!}

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="box box-primary">
      <div class="box-header with-border ">
        <h3 class="box-title">Detalles del Cliente
          <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"  id="btn-btn-client"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" ></i> Nuevo Cliente</button>                      -->
          <a id="btn-btn-client" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-top: -8px;" title="Crear Cliente"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Crear</a>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Nombre empresa</label>
          <select name="name_company" id="name_company" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Seleciona empresa</option>
            @foreach ($clients as $client)
            <option value="{{ $client->company['id'] }}" {{ old( 'name_company', $order->client_id) == $client->company['id'] ? 'selected' : ''}}> {{ $client->company['name_company'] }}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('phone_company', 'Telefono empresa:') !!} @if ($order->exists) @foreach ($clients as $client) @if(old('phone_company', $order->client_id) == $client->company['id']) {!! Form::text('phone_company', old('phone_company', $client->company['phone_company']),
          ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone_company', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'placeholder' => 'Telefono empresa']) !!} @endif @endforeach @else {!! Form::text('phone_company', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone_company', 'disabled'
          => 'disabled', 'placeholder' => 'Telefono empresa']) !!} @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('name_client', 'Nombre contacto:') !!} @if ($order->exists) @foreach ($clients as $client) @if(old('name_client', $order->client_id) == $client->company['id']) {!! Form::text('name_client', old('name_client', $client['name_client']), ['class'
          => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name_client', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre contacto']) !!} @endif @endforeach @else {!! Form::text('name_client', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name_client', 'disabled' => 'disabled',
          'placeholder' => 'Nombre contacto']) !!} @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('phone_client', 'Telefono contacto:') !!} @if ($order->exists) @foreach ($clients as $client) @if(old('phone_client', $order->client_id) == $client->company['id']) {!! Form::text('phone_client', old('phone_client', $client['phone_client']),
          ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone_client', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'placeholder' => 'Telefono contacto']) !!} @endif @endforeach @else {!! Form::text('phone_client', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone_client', 'disabled'
          => 'disabled', 'placeholder' => 'Telefono contacto']) !!} @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('email', 'Email contacto:') !!} @if ($order->exists) @foreach ($clients as $client) @if(old('email', $order->client_id) == $client->company['id']) {!! Form::text('email', old('email', $client['email']), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id'
          => 'email', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'placeholder' => 'Email contacto']) !!} @endif @endforeach @else {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'placeholder' => 'Email contacto']) !!}
          @endif
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Formulario **crear clientes**:

```
{!! Form::model($client, [ 'route' => $client->exists ? ['admin.customers.update', $client->id] : 'admin.customers.store', 'method' => $client->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST' ]) !!}

<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#activity" data-toggle="tab" id="empresa">Empresa</a></li>
    <li><a href="#timeline" data-toggle="tab" id="contacto">Contacto</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab" id="direccion">Dirección</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="active tab-pane" id="activity">
      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name_company', 'Nombre') !!} {!! Form::text('name_company', $client->company['name_company'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name_company']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('cuit', 'Cuit') !!} {!! Form::text('cuit', $client->company['cuit'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'cuit']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('web', 'Web') !!} {!! Form::text('web', $client->company['web'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'web']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('phone_company', 'Telefono') !!} {!! Form::text('phone_company', $client->company['phone_company'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone_company']) !!}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="timeline">
      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name_client', 'Nombres') !!} {!! Form::text('name_client', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name_client']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('lastname', 'Apellidos') !!} {!! Form::text('lastname', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'lastname']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email') !!} {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('phone_client', 'Telefono') !!} {!! Form::text('phone_client', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'phone_client']) !!}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">
      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('address', 'Direccion') !!} {!! Form::text('address', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'address']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('city', 'Ciudad') !!} {!! Form::text('city', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'city']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('province', 'Provincia') !!} {!! Form::text('province', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'province']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('postal_code', 'Codigo Postal') !!} {!! Form::text('postal_code', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'postal_code']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('country', 'Pais') !!} {!! Form::text('country', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'country']) !!}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Rutas**:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix'     => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'auth'],   
function(){    
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
    Route::resource('customers',    'ClientController', ['as' => 'admin']);   
    Route::resource('orders',       'OrderController', ['as' => 'admin']);
```

No puedo darme cuenta cuál es el error.